# Python Scipy Optimizer Minimize : Constraints and bounds are not working as expected, how to make it work?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

The function to be optimized:

```
def optimize(allocs, allStocksNormalized):
    allocs = allStocksNormalized * allocs
    postvalues = allocs * startvalue
    portfolioValues = postvalues.sum(axis=1)
    cumulativeReturns = (portfolioValues[-1] / portfolioValues[0]) - 1
    return cumulativeReturns*-1
```

Calling function:

```
allocsGuess = [0.3,0.3,0.3,0.1]

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun' : lambda inputs: 1 - (np.sum(abs(inputs)))})

bnds = [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0)]

min_cum_return = optimizer.minimize(optimize, allocsGuess, args=(allStocksNormalized,) ,
                                   method='SLSQP',  bounds=bnds, constraints=cons,
                                    options={'disp': True})

print("X = {}, Y = {}".format(min_cum_return.x,min_cum_return.fun))
```

Now this is returning results like this -

```
X = [  3.47499807e-14   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00], Y = -14.500342231347526
```

I want constraints for following conditions -

1. Each value in allocation array (X) should be in between 0.0 & 1.0 (I'm using bounds for this)
2. The sum of the absolute values of array X should be exactly equal to 1.0 (I'm using constraints for this)

As we can see, the results I get from X array does not fit into either of the criteria.

How can I improve this to make it work?

Comment: How do your results not fit those criteria?

Comment: @DonkeyKong X[0] is 3.47 which is greater than 1.0, sum of all values of X is greater than 0.
How can I improve my constraints code to fit into the conditions I've mentioned?

Comment: It is 3.47 x 10 ^ -14, which is effectively 0.

Comment: @DonkeyKong oh thanks! silly me! :-)

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
bnds = ((0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0))
```

bnds should be a tuple